# Edit an object which is in an array of objects in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I have a very basic comment widget application where I can add new comments. I'm trying to add the ability to edit a comment as well.
I have the following data to initialize my comments:

```
const data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        comment: "Test Comment"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        comment: "Second Comment",
        subComments: [
            {
                comment: "Sub second comment 1"
            },
            {
                comment: "Sub second comment 2"
            },
            {
                comment: "Sub second comment 3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        comment: "How much is 2 + 2?",
        subComments: [
            {
                comment: "It is 5",
                subComments: [
                    {
                        comment: "No, it's 4."
                    }
                ],
            },
            {
                comment: "4!",
            },
            {
                comment: "Is this a joke?"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Then, I have my application where I am successfully displaying the comments and adding new comments.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const Comment = () => {

    const [ comments, setComments ] = useState([])
    const [ commentText, setCommentText ] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        setComments(data);
    }, []);

    const handleChangeCommentText = (event) => {
        setCommentText(event.target.value);
    }

    const handleAddComment = () => {
        if(commentText === '') {
            alert('Please, enter a comment.');
            return;
        }
        const newId = parseInt(comments[comments.length-1].id) + 1;
        const newObj = {
            id: newId,
            comment: commentText
        }
        setComments((prevComments) => {
            const arr = [...prevComments]
            arr.push(newObj);
            return arr;
        });
        setCommentText("");
    }

    const handleReplyComment = (commentIndex, subCommentsIndex) => {
        if(commentText === '') {
            alert('Please, enter a comment');
            return;
        }
        // How can I go all the way to the correct subCommentIndex to update its comment?
    }

    const showSubComments = (subComments, margin, commentIndex, subCommentIndex) => {
        if(subComments.length === 0)
            return;
        
        return subComments.map((obj, index) => {
            const temp = [...subCommentIndex];
            temp.push(index)
            return (
                <>
                    <br />
                    <span style={{marginLeft: `${margin}rem`}}>
                        {obj.comment} 
                        <button type="button" onClick={() => handleReplyComment(commentIndex, temp)}>Reply</button>
                    </span>
                    {showSubComments(obj.subComments || [], margin+2, commentIndex, temp)}
                </>
            )
        });
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <textarea type="textarea" value={commentText} rows={5} cols={50} onChange={handleChangeCommentText} />
                <button type="button" onClick={handleAddComment}>Add Comment</button>
                <div>
                    {comments.map((obj, index) => {
                        return (
                            <div key={index}>
                                <span>{obj.comment} <button type="button">Reply</button></span>
                                {showSubComments(obj.subComments || [], 2, index, [])}
                            </div>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>    
            </div>   
        </>
    );
}

export default Comment;
```

I'm stuck in the `handleReplyComment` method. My first idea is working with the indices of the arrays, but it become very messy and I couldn't continue the code. Any idea of how I could do it?

Thanks

Comment: If i add a reply should it be sub-comment ? . Also is it possible to have sub-comments for sub-comments ? If yes then how much level of nesting ?

Comment: Yes and yes. Unlimited nested levels